# Stencil - How to get CDN links from javascript

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I'm working with Big Commerce's stencil to add some advanced functionality to my product pages. Part of this functionality requires files to be loaded from the server. Each product page would need a different file so I can't just use {{cdn ...}} in the template file, I need the equivalent of that in javascript

Template File:
`{{cdn "mydogpicture.jpg"}}`
outputs **www.cdn.bigcommerce.com/some/link/mydogpicture.jpg**

I need something like
`var linkToDogPicture = loadFileFromServer("mydogpicture.jpg");`
so then I could use that link to load the file where I need it (It wouldn't always be a picture file)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use a custom field to store the value "mydogpicture.jpg" and then access *this* in your template ?

Comment: That's actually the solution I came to at the end of the day yesterday. Being that the files are different for each product page I can't store each file in the template because at the time the template is rendered, the page doesn't know which files it needs. My workaround right now is I've stored a blank .json file in the root of the /content folder and I use {{cdn "myfile.json"}} to output the link into an invisible <span> then I just remove the myfile.json part and append the paths I need as I load files. Overly complicated for something so simple, so I was hoping there was an easier way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked this on both Stackoverflow and the BigCommerce forums and there doesn't seem to be a cleaner solution so I'll go ahead and post my work around as the answer. Defining the CDN links in the custom fields doesn't work for two reasons: The files needed aren't known until the javascript loads a configuration json file from the server and I want to make sure the end user is getting the cdn link pointing to the server closest to them to take advantage of CDN. Here's how I'm doing it:

1. Upload a file to the root of your **/content** directory. This file can be blank, you just need to know the name of it and never change the name. In my case, I called it **cdn.json**
2. In your template file use

`<span id="cdn_link" style="display: none">{{cdn "cdn.json"}}</span>`

to put the CDN link to cdn.json in an invisible span on the page. The cdn function should output something like **httpx://cdnX.bigcommerce.com/xxxxxx/cdn.json**

3. In javascript, get the innerhtml of the span and remove **cdn.json**

`var cdnLink = $("#cdn_link").html();
cdnLink = cdnLink.replace("version.json", "");`

Now you can append paths to **cdnLink** to load files from the CDN server BigCommerce chooses as the fastest for the user

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a simpler solution is to add the following to your `base.html` template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cdn(path) {
        return `{{ cdn '/' }}${path}`;
    }
</script>
```

Then whenever you need a CDN path for an asset in your javascript you can:

```
image.src = cdn('/img/logo.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [Custom Fields](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Custom-Fields) feature of BigCommerce.

- For each product, add the CDN link as a custom field.
- Your custom field should automatically display on the product page.